# fast approach to read several files in a list comprehension

Tags: python, optimization, file-io, list-comprehension

I have a folder with several text file (ex: 164400). Each file has several lines (ex: x,y,z) in numeric floating format. My code reads a group of 3000 files at times and stores the values in the lines a dictionary (see example).

The code is quite slow when opening 3000 files.

```
[[points_dict[os.path.split(x)[1]].append(p) for p in open(x,"r")] for x in lf]
```

I wish to know if someone has a more efficient and fast approach to read the files

```
file_folder = "C:\\junk" #where i stored my file
points_dict = defaultdict(list)
groups = groupby(file_folder, key=lambda k, line=count(): next(line) // 3000)
for k, group in groups:
    lf = [p for p in group]
    [[points_dict[os.path.split(x)[1]].append(p) for p in open(x,"r")] for x in lf]
# do other
```

where the function `**os.path.split(x)[1]**` stores the lines with the same file name (id) in the dictionary and `**lf**` is the list of the files to open

Comment: How about just concatenating the contents of the files into a single file?  Perhaps with one added column to indicate the source.

Comment: i was thinking about this but i need always to read all file to concatenating in a single file

Comment: How long does it take to load 3000 files?

Comment: around 25 sec 3000 files

Comment: may be a good candidate for a `multiprocessing.Pool`, and perhaps it's time to unpack your list comprehension, it's hard to see what your trying to do.

Comment: now reads 3000 in 11 sec (see modification in the code)

Comment: There's no reason to use a list comprehension here, just unpack it into loops. It won't be any faster but it'll be much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

What about using numpy ? Something along those lines (*edited answer, tested code*)

```
[points_dict[os.path.split(x)[1]].append(numpy.loadtxt(x, delimiter=",")) for x in lf]
for x, np_arrays in points_dict.iteritems():
    points_dict[x]=numpy.vstack(np_arrays)
```

At the end you get the points in a nice numpy array.